# Question about Australian international arrivals

Tags: immigration, australia

I read on the ABP website that they may fingerprint international arrivals. Is it something they do for everyone, or only randomly?

Comment: Another case is possible: maybe not everyone, and not randomly, but according to some unknown and unpublished rules and conditions.

Comment: Is this an expats question or should it be moved to Travel Stack Exchange (I suspect the later.)